# Background image not loading in browser. File path correct

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've run into a situation I can't solve. The file path for background image "rs_dyslexia_montage_1.jpg" appears to be correct, but Chrome developer tools shows that it's not loading. The header image on the page is located in the same folder, has the same file path and loads fine. Not sure what is happening here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS- I included additional code above the problem areas in case it's needed for troubleshooting.

The HTML:

```
<div class="what_now dyslexia_cta col span_6">
    <div>
        <h1>WHAT NOW?</h1>
        <p>Fenean et tortor vel magna sporta eleifend ac leo. Pellentesque dignis.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class= "resources dyslexia_cta col span_6">
    <div>
        <h1>RESOURCES</h1>
        <p>For additional information, please click on the resources button.</p>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="dys_mont_pic1 col span_12"></div>
<div class="dys_mont_pic2 col span_6"></div>
<div class="dys_mont_pic3 col span_6"></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.pad_btm {
padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.what_now {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: 400px;  
background-color: rgb(165,191,57);
background-repeat: none;
background-size: cover; 
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.resources {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: 400px;
float: right;
background-color: rgb(66,121,160);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.dyslexia_cta h1 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 52px;
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0px 60px;
padding: 27px 10px 27px 10px;
border: 3px solid white;
}

.dyslexia_cta p {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Questrial';
color: rgb(255,255,255);
line-height: 28px;
font-size: 20px;
max-width: 550px;
padding: 20px 100px 0px;    

.dys_mont_pic1 {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;  
background-image: url('../img/rs_dyslexia_montage_1.jpg');
background-repeat: none;
background-size: cover;
border-bottom: 7px solid white; 
}
```

Comment: You are missing a curly brace after the .dyslexia_cta p{ missing the closing }

Comment: Geez, I've been staring for quite some time and didn't catch that. Thanks for pointing it out.